# Replication issue between Master and Slave while altering table with Default in mysql 5.6 (Innodb)

Tags: mysql

```
create table test_random (
a varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
b varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

### Master schema

mysql> desc test_random;

| Field | Type___ | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | varchar(50) | NO | ____ | ______ |  |
| b | varchar(50) | NO | ____ | ______ |  |

### Slave Schema

mysql> desc test_random;

| Field | Type___ | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | varchar(50) | NO | ____ | ______ |  |
| b | varchar(50) | NO | ____ | ______ |  |

Then i ran the alter command on master for changing the table
`ALTER TABLE test.test_random` ADD created `TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT` `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `ADD last_updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

### Master Schema after `ALTER` command

mysql> desc test_random;

| Field___ | Type______ | Null_ | Key_ | Default_______ | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a______ | varchar(50) | NO |  |  |  |
| b______ | varchar(50) | NO |  |  |  |

| created | timestamp | NO |  | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| last_updated | timestamp | NO |  | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | on update | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |

### Slave Schema after `ALTER` command in the master

mysql> desc test_random;

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | varchar(50) | NO |  |  |  |
| b | varchar(50) | NO |  |  |  |

| created | timestamp | NO |  | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| last_updated | timestamp | NO |  | NULL | on update | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |

The last_updated column in Master is Default `0000-00-00 00:00:00` which has changed to Default Null in slave.  Can you please help with why does the schema change between master and slave on the same ALTER command?